# Smallcaps / multiple fonts and bolding using 'DrawString' in GDI+

Tags: .net, asp.net, gdi+, system.drawing, drawstring

I want to write out some text using [smallcaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) in combination with different fonts for different words.

To clarify I might want the message 'Welcome to our New Website' which is generated into a PNG file for the header of a page.

- The text will be [smallcaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) - everything is capitalized but the 'W', 'N' and 'W' are slightly larger.
- The 'New Website' will be in a different font than the rest of the text.

Is there a way i can do this without doing it completely manually?

Doing something like this is conceptually what I want to do :

```
 graphics.DrawString("<font size=2>W</font>ELCOME TO OUR <b><font size=2>N</font>" +
                     "EW <font size=2>W</font>EBSITE</b>");
```

The best approach I could find so far [is here](http://blogs.vbcity.com/xtab/archive/2005/11/02/5669.aspx), but I'm worried that I'll go to all the trouble to do this manually and end up with some horrible [kerning or tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)  problems.

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that this is being done within ASP.NET so it needs to be fast and as lean as possible. I want it to be automated so I can localize easily and not have to create tonnes of little images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you should really be using a RichTextBox here... there is a method to extract a bitmap from the RichTextBox which you could then render as a bitmap to your graphics context. Of course, you'd need to make a Managed C++ call here and I don't know if you're able to do that in your project.

Otherwise, I think you will need to do it manually with DrawString and MeasureString, which is a pain.

Comment: this is ASP.NET :-) i'll add that above !

Comment: well i guess part two of your answer is correct :) im trying to up my accept ratio